# understanding the type signature of (.)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm just learning Haskell and functional programming using Richard Bird's book and came across the type signature of the (.) function. Namely

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

and the associated definition

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

I understand what the operator is doing but am a bit confused about how to read the type signature. Is it saying that (.) takes as its first argument a function of type (b -> c), then returns a function of type (a -> b), and finally returns a function of type (a -> c)? Is this the right way to read the type signature?

Also, could this be an example of currying, where (.) is a curried function that takes two parameters? Or is that not the correct way to think about currying?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've almost got it, it takes a `b -> c` and returns a function `(a -> b) -> (a -> c)` which, when given an `(a -> b)` returns a function `a -> c`. It may also be helpful to know that in Haskell, you can wrap an operator in parens and use it prefix so

```
f . g === (.) f g
```

Now it's easier to see the currying

```
((.) f) g === f . g
```

Finally, notice that this type signature is equivalent to

```
(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Since `->` is right associative.

Answer (score 4):

You can read function signatures with several arguments like this:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
```

so, `(f .) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`

Next is the same:

```
foo :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e

foo :: a ->(b ->(c ->(d -> e)))
```

Function `(.)` takes 2 functions `(a -> b)` as a parameters and return their composition